# Drupal 6 and Backlinks

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Just installed Drupal 6, CCK 2.3 and Views 2.5 and I'm trying to get backlinks. Every tutorial I see says that there is a backlinks view by default and I should activate it, but there is none. The only available views are: archive, comments_recent, frontpage, glossary, taxonomy_term & tracker :(

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the backlinks view available, you need to enable Drupal's core search module. The reason for this is that the backlinks view works off of the search indexes.